# jQuery UI Theme Roller - Prior Versions

Tags: jquery-ui, themeroller

I need to use jQuery UI Theme Roller for use with jQuery UI 1.8.16....is there a way to generate a theme for a prior version of jQuery UI ?

Answer (score 2):

http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

When you click "Download", you'll be able to choose the version 1.8.24 or even 1.7.3.